# What is the approximate equality in LDAP filters?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I'm using JNDI with LDAP and Active Directory.

According to the [filter page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/filter.html), there is a symbol `~=` that has the following description:

> ~=      approximate equality (according to the matching rule of the attribute)

What does it mean?

I was thinking that there was something like a Levenshtein distance between the input and and Active Directory attributes values and that distance has to be less than a threshold, but it seems that it doesn't work in this way.

I tried the following example:

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(
    "dc=x,dc=y,dc=z",    // name
    "(cn~=John Smith)",  // filter
    searchCtls           // controls
);
```

which returns exactly the same entries as

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(
    "dc=x,dc=y,dc=z",    // name
    "(cn=John Smith)",   // filter
    searchCtls           // controls
);
```

which is fine, but it returns nothing if I use:

```
    "(cn~=jJohn Smith)", // filter
```

or

```
    "(cn~=ohn Smith)",   // filter
```

or

```
    "(cn~=Gohn Smith)",  // filter
```

or

```
    "(cn~=JohnSmith)",   // filter
```

The results were similar when I chose an integer instead of that string (E.g.: `abc~=123` instead of `cn~=John Smith`).

So, I don't see the difference between `=` and `~=`.

---

**Edit:**

I found a difference, but this was not the expected one.

This doesn't return anything:

```
    "(cn~=J*n Smith)",   // filter
```

while this returns the `John Smith` entry:

```
    "(cn=J*n Smith)",   // filter
```

Comment: It's not defined by JNDI but by LDAP, in [RFC 4511](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/apc/rfc4511.txt).

Answer (score 2):

Although approxMatch is mentioned in RFC 4511, there are no specifications that define how it is to be implemented or used. So the approxMatch is left to the LDAP server implementation on how it works.

IMHO, it was "intended" to be used as 'sounds-like' algorithm.

[Approximate Match Filters](https://www.ldap.com/ldap-filters)

> An approximate match filter may be used to determine whether an entry contains at least one value for a specified attribute that is approximately equal to a given value. The LDAP specifications do not define what exactly "approximately equal to" means, so that is left up to individual server implementations to determine. Many servers use a "sounds like" mechanism with an algorithm based on Soundex or one of the Metaphone variants.
>
> The string representation of an approximate match filter is constructed as follows:
>
> - An open parenthesis
> - The attribute description (potentially including attribute options)
> - A tilde character
> - An equal sign
> - The value to compare (aka the assertion value)
> - A close parenthesis
>
> For example, it might be reasonable to expect a filter of "(givenName~=John)" to match entries with givenName values of either John or Jon.
>
> Although it seems like a significant oversight or omission, the LDAP specifications do not make any provision for approximate matching rules. A number of directory servers provide this capability anyway so that it may be possible to configure the approximate match behavior on a per-attribute basis, but the inconsistency of approximate matching capabilities between server implementations makes approximate matching something that is often avoided in LDAP-enabled applications.